# How can I use io.card aar library in the eclipse project maven

Tags: android, eclipse, maven, aar

I would like to add io.card library in the dependency of my Eclipse project pom.xml
But Here When I added the dependency in my pom.xml i am getting an error

Here is my pom file

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.card</groupId>
    <artifactId>android-sdk</artifactId>
    <version>5.5.0</version>
    <type>aar</type>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
```

It's downloading the jar file properly but still showing can not find symbol cardIOActivity

Will it be possible to use aar in the maven eclipse project, if No is there any alternative solution for this.

my Error is

```
/android/app/paymentsUtil/PaymentUtil.java:[40,23] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class CardIOActivity
```

Comment: You have to place the aar in a lokal maven repository then reference it as you do.

Comment: I have done it as you said but still results in an error

Comment: Correct folder structure, all metadata?

Comment: It's older and for Gradle but could help. https://www.slideshare.net/mobile/RenMertins/get-startedwithaar-pdfexportrem20141012?qid=77186186-b57d-4010-922d-86598125e142&v=&b=&from_search=1